# Line up decimals on print

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
meal_cost = float(input(" Please Enter the Meal Cost:$"))
percent_tip = float(input(" Please Enter the percent of the tip:%"))
meal_tax = float(input(" Whats the sales tax:%"))
sales_tax = meal_tax / 100
tax = sales_tax * meal_cost
taxA = str(round(tax, 2))
tip = percent_tip / 100
tip_total = tip * meal_cost
final_tip = str(round(tip_total, 2))
subtotal =  tip_total + meal_cost + tax
total = str(round(subtotal, 2))
print()
```

This is where I need help. I need help when formatting all the decimals posts for my answers to that they can be aligned.

For example, lined up like this:

```
    23.52
     1.55
   100.50


print('Subtotal $', \
      format(meal_cost, '.2f'))

print('Gratuity $', \
      format(final_tip, '.2f'))

print('Sales Tax $', \
      format(TaxA, '.2f'))

print('Total $', \
      format(total, '.2f'))
```

Comment: Please add an example of the desired output so that we may help you get it right.

Comment: For example,. Lined up like this
23.52
   1.55
100.50

Comment: @KEVIN, try ```print("Total $ {0:.2f}".format(total))```

Comment: @BiarysI am getting the message unknown format code "f" for object of type "str"

Comment: Do not use str() to convert your calculated values to string. The format string ```{0:.2f}``` expects a number, not a string as input.

Answer (score 2):

You want to *right-align* the string representation of your numbers so that their decimal points are aligned.

You tell Python to do this by including a `>` character in your format specification.  You also need to tell Python how wide you want each string to be, and which character to use to pad out the string if it isn't as wide as the width that you specified.

The format you want look like this:

`' >10.2f'`

From left to right, its components are:

- A space: the string will be left-padded with spaces to make up the width
- `>` indicating that the string will be right-aligned
- `10` indicating that the formatted string will be ten characters wide
- `.2` indicating the string will display two decimal places
- `f` indicating the string will displayed using fixed point notation

The output looks like this:

```
>>> nums = [23.52, 1.55, 100.5]
>>> for n in nums:
...     print(format(n, ' >10.2f'))
... 
     23.52
      1.55
    100.50
>>>
```